# Write Persian in slug and use it in address bar in django

Tags: python, django, persian

I use django and in my models I want to write Persian in slugfield (by using utf-8 or something else) and use the slug in address of page 
I write this class for model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    meta_description = models.TextField(max_length=160, null=True, blank=True)
    meta_keywords = models.TextField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def category_posts(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(category=self).count()
```

But there is nothing in slug column after save and I don't know what to write in url to show Persian. Can you tell me what should I do?

I use django 1.9 and python 3.6.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [docstring](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.9.13/django/utils/text.py#L415) for the `slugify` function is:

> Convert to ASCII if 'allow_unicode' is False. Convert spaces to hyphens.
>   Remove characters that aren't alphanumerics, underscores, or hyphens.
>   Convert to lowercase. Also strip leading and trailing whitespace.

So you need to set the `allow_unicode` flag to `True` to preserve the Persian text.

```
>>> text = 'سلام عزیزم! عزیزم سلام!'
>>> slugify(text)
''
>>> slugify(text, allow_unicode=True)
'سلام-عزیزم-عزیزم-سلام'
>>>
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Reverse for 'system-detail' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'هفت'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['system/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\\Z']

Comment: @Darwin the regex part of the pattern in your comment only matches upper and lower case alphabetical characters (`a-zA-Z`).  If you want to match characters in the entire unicode range, use `\w`: `'system/(?P<slug>[-\\w0-9_]+)/\\Z'`

Answer (score 2):

this is better !!

```
‍‍‍slug = models.SlugField(max_length=20, unique=True, allow_unicode=True)
```

Comment: Can you explain in your answer why "this is better !!"?

Comment: This does not work for me. Reverse for 'system-detail' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'هفت'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['system/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\\Z']

Answer (score 1):

Here`s an example which you can use for this case:

First install `django_extensions` with `pip`, if it is not installed.

```py
from django_extensions.db.fields import AutoSlugField
from django.utils.text import slugify
```

In `model.py` before your class add this function:

```py
def my_slugify_function(content):
    return slugify(content, allow_unicode=True)
```

In your class add this field:

```py
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from=['name'], unique=True, allow_unicode=True, slugify_function=my_slugify_function)
```

In url must use this format:

```py
re_path('person_list/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/', views.detail, name='detail')
```

Answer (score -1):

I used snakecharmerb and Ali Noori answers. But those did not solve my problem. And get this error:

```
Reverse for 'system-detail' with keyword arguments '{'slug': 'هفت'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['system/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\\Z']
```

In urls.py i Change slug to str:

```
path('<str:slug>/', SystemDetailView.as_view(), name='system-detail'),
```

Comment: As I commented in response to your comment on my answer, the character class `[-a-zA-Z0-9_]` in the url pattern only matches _ASCII_ strings.  If you want to matches non-ASCII characters consider at least `[-\w0-9_]`, or even `[-\w\d_]` to match non-ASCII digits as well.